# using a href instead of input

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have an AJAX function, and I am bad at AJAX. I want to pass a value from PHP to AJAX. I managed to do this by using:

```
<input type="text" id="price" onclick='ajaxFunction()' value="<?php echo $id; ?>" />
```

And then in my AJAX:

```
document.getElementById('price').value;
```

But I would like to make it working by using HTML a href.

Can anyone help me with possible ways of doing this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Make what work? If you just want an anchor, why not create an anchor instead.

Comment: How can I get the value from an A href, thats the question.

Comment: @Tibor replace value by href?!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An `anchor` or `<a>` tag doesn't have a `value`, instead it has `innerHTML`. Use this way:

```
<a id="price" href="#something">50.00</a>
```

```js
document.getElementById('price').innerHTML; // 50.00
document.getElementById('price').getAttribute("href"); // #something
```

To set these values, you can use the same stuff:

```js
document.getElementById('price').innerHTML = responseText;
document.getElementById('price').setAttribute("href", responseText);
```

And as always, it is better to respond as JSON for nice stuff:

```
responseText = {
    "price": 50.00,
    "link":  '#something'
};
```

The above when PHP is outputs, it would be:

```
<?php header ("Content-type: application/json"); ?>
{
    "price": 50.00,
    "link":  '#something'
}
```

And you can use it as:

```js
document.getElementById('price').innerHTML = responseText.price;
document.getElementById('price').setAttribute("href", responseText.link);
```

Since you have added [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery), I guess adding this info will make this answer worth. I am not sure how you are calling the AJAX function, but calling this way is awesome. jQuery has a built in AJAX function, which you can use:

```
$.post("path/to/php", {data: to_be_sent}, function (responseText) {
    responseText = JSON.parse(responseText);
    $("#price").attr("href", responseText.link).html(responseText.price);
});
```

Reading is far more easier in this case:

```
$("#price").attr("href", responseText.link); // Gives you the #something
$("#price").html(responseText.price);        // Gives you the 50.00
```

Comment: `make it working by using HTML a href` Oh, so now i understand the question ;) I was guessing OP wanted to get the href property

Comment: I added more points @A.Wolff, as the OP's question wasn't clear!